# What is wrong with the shape of my input array for a Keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a trained [keras](/questions/tagged/keras) model for image classification. That model is based on the **Xception** model shipped with Keras, it expects the input images in a size of `299x299` pixels. So I resize my images to that format before feeding them into my model.

However, when calling `model.predict(img)` I do get the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model:expected shape=(None, 299, 299, 3), found shape=(None, 299, 3)
```

But when I inspect `img` at the call to `predict()` in the debugger I can see the following:

```
shape:(299, 299, 3)
```

Can somebody explain to me what I am missing here?

Comment: As a comment, you probably should not use `model.predict` on 1 image. This function is used to predict large batches of data, and performance on a a single sample are usually terrible. Instead, just call your model: `model(img)`.

Comment: @Lescurel Wow, thanks,, didn't know that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your Keras model expects data in this format `(n_sample, 299, 299, 3)`

A simple reshape when you predict a single image does the trick

```
model.predict(X.reshape(1, 299, 299, 3))
```